# Looping for the macro

Tags: excel, vba, byval

I have the following problem:

I created a macro that locks rows for specific ranges (B20:Y20) in my excel spreadsheet and paints the locked rows with a specific color. Furthermore it creates a timestamp for the locked rows in Y20. The condition for the cell lock is that the value of column B20 is not empty.

When I activate the macro it should first be checked whether cell B20 has a value > 0. If this is the case, the row for the specified range is locked and colored and the timestamp is added.

The goal would now be to perform the identical procedure for the next row (Range B21:Y21) when B21 has a value of >0. 
This leads to my problem: How can I "roll forward" my macro to be performed in the continuing rows?

From my point of view the goal would be to adjust all ranks of my code so that the columns and rows become "dynamic" and cannot be executed "rigidly" for only one specific line as currently displayed.

Does anyone have an idea how my code could be adjusted in a way that by activating the macro the next rows that are >0 for column B are used for processing?

Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
Sub Check()

If ActiveSheet.Range("B20") = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Check Input Data.", vbOKOnly, "Error"
Else
    Call Savepostings
End If

End Sub

Sub protectrow()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A20:Y20")
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="A"
rng.Interior.Color = vbRed
rng.Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="A", DrawingObjects:=True, _
        Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, _
        userinterfaceonly:=True
ActiveSheet.EnableAutoFilter = True

End Sub

Sub Savepostings()

If Cells(13, 2) = "ERROR" Then
    MsgBox "Error", vbOKOnly, "Error"
Else
    MsgBox "OK", vbOKOnly, "OK"

    Call printtime
    Call protectrow
End If

End Sub

Sub printtime()

Cells(20, 24) = printUserName
Cells(20, 25) = printTimeStamp

End Sub

Function printUserName() As String
printUserName = Application.UserName
End Function

Function printTimeStamp() As String
printTimeStamp = Now()
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Take a look to [offset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset).

Comment: Hi, thank you very much! - Do you know where exactly to put the offset function?

Comment: You can use, f.e., `Range("A20:Y20").Offset(1,0)` that will take the range from A21:Y21. In order to loop you should take a look to [For Loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement)

Comment: You Don't need to use `Offset`; use a `For Loop` to loop through each cell in Column B starting at Row 20 to the last row with data.

Comment: Ok i think i will use the loop through each cell in Column B. But for the implementation i need to set a variable for Row 20 right? Because when i change the Sub Check () to loop, the other subs stay with row 20...

Comment: That is correct; you will have to use a variable to input the `UserName` etc. e.g. `Cells(x, 24)` where x = the current row in the loop. If you have trouble with the loop it should look like this `For x = 20 to LastRow`

Comment: Ok so am i right when defining the x by Function Loop() For x=20 to 300 Next x End Function and replacing all cells in the subs by an x? Because if i do this i receive errors